# A way to trim div (or any element) with parents div (CSS)

Tags: css, position, transition, trim

Have three questions:

1. How can I make yellow circle (child div) to be trimmed when it crosses its parent red border so I see only yellow square ? (using only CSS)
2. How is it possible to fix circle by its center when it grows? Now its fixed by top left corner.
3. If I use "position: fixed" and then declare top: 10px; left: 10px; How can I add CSS transition to "top" and "left" properties ?

```css
.parent {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: salmon;
border: 5px solid red;
}
.child {
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background-color: yellow;
border: 2px solid blue;
border-radius: 50%;
}
.child:active {
width: 350px;
height: 350px;
transition: width 2s linear, height 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `overflow: hidden` on parent div.
2. If it's the child you want to fix, put the following on the parent. `display: grid` and `place-items: center`. That is by far the easiest way to centre an element.
3. This question is not entirely clear.
   You can certainly add "position: fixed" and "top: 10px"; "left: 10px" to any div.
   If you mean to animate it on active then simply add the different values to those particular css attributes to your child:active class.

Comment: 3. Sorry for being unclear. I meant how should I declare transition to make e.g. top change from 0 to 10px with animation. transition: top 1s linear does not work.

Comment: Ok, that isn't listed on the example, so I imagine you are trying to do that with a different div? 
If you write `transition: all 1s linear` on the elements that are changing `top` and `left` values, it should work.
Also, remember the parent of any `position: absolute` element must be `position: relative`. Perhaps that's stopping it.
If that doesn't, perhaps edit the code that's already on here to show a more detailed example.